# Relating to multiple categories?

Tags: relations

Bit of an odd one here I can't quite work out. It's late and my brain is melting.

I am creating an Artist listing page. It is a Single where the client can pick which category of Artist they want to be listed. They do this via a category field on the Single.

I have a channel of Artists, and each artist has a Category field where they can be listed as playing in a given category. All simple enough so far.

The categories look like this:

[image: categories]

My problem: how do I loop through the artists and group them by their sub-categories? For example - the client has decided that on the listing page they want to list Ymuno Summer 2011. I need to then spit out all related artists, grouped by Friday and Saturday. An artist may be performing on more than one day.

So far I've stripped things back as far as:

```
{% if entry.featuredLineup | length %}
    {% set artistsInLineup = craft.entries.section('artists').relatedTo(entry.featuredLineup) %}

    {% for artist in artistsInLineup %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But even that isn't spitting anything out at all, other than getting into the outer conditional. I feel like I'm making a rookie mistake, but everything I've seen in the docs is hard-coded relations rather than pulling from an entry field. I'm not even sure I'm thinking straight about the problem anymore.